# LoopBack installation failed with error code "ECONNRESET"

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I wanted follow [this tutorial](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-java-getting-started/) and one of the first steps - the installation of [LoopBack](http://loopback.io/) failed.
The `type npm-debug.log` tells:

```
41099 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"
 "install" "-g" "strongloop"
41100 error node v0.12.2
41101 error npm  v2.7.4
41102 error code ECONNRESET
41103 error errno ECONNRESET
41104 error syscall read
41105 error network read ECONNRESET
41105 error network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
41105 error network and is related to network connectivity.
41105 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
41105 error network
41105 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
41105 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
41106 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

The most confusing lines are:

> This is most likely not a problem with npm itself 
>   In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings

I'm not behind a proxy, and the fact, that I'm posting the question to SO from the same machine makes me assume, that network-settings are OK. What could be wrong here?

P.S:Looking at other question concerning node.js, the hope that this one will be answered and the wish to follow node-path are disappearing.

Comment: If you haven't done so, try simply installing loopback a second time to make sure it wasn't just a temporary network blip.

Comment: OK! that helped. I wonder, why there were no hint in the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Putting this answer that I initially wrote as a comment here because OP says it worked for them.)

If, as you say, you are not behind a proxy, etc., install a second time. There may have just been a temporary network blip on your end or anywhere in between you and the npm registry.

Comment: I wonder, if it worked with all node-errors. One additional source of my former errors seems to be the absence of VS2012. I was not aware, that npm calls a compiler. However in this tutorial, though the calling VisualStudio failed, I was able to follow the tutorial and loopback worked.

Comment: npm itself probably does not call the compiler, but a package can have pre-install and post-install steps that can do pretty much anything.